# dojo: using registry.byID returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I have problems to retrieve a button-widget with dojo/registry.

I have a widget and inside it's `postCreate`-function some other functions are called. In the last one `registry.byId()` returns "undefined" causing an error. The element with the provided id does exist in the html-template.

I have also created an very simple working version in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x3dat6e/14/) and even if I try this variant in my code I get "undefined". **EDIT:** updated Fiddle

Here is a short summary of the code with the original use of `registry.byId()` in the _setupButton-function and also with the solution from the JSFiddle before the `declare`-part. Both versions return "undefined":

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/number", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojo/text!./templates/template.html"],
function(declare, array, lang, domClass, number, parser, ready, domconstruct, registry, NumberTextBox, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, Menu, MenuItem, templateStringContent) {

parser.parse();
ready(function () {
     console.info(registry.byId("startCalculationButton"));
});

return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin],
{
    templateString: templateStringContent,

    postCreate() {
       this._setupButton();
    },
    _setupButton: function() {
       buttonWidget = registry.byId("startCalculationButton");
       buttonWidget.set("disabled", true);
    },
});
```

});

The html is the same as in the provided JSFiddle-Snippet. Other id's (for toher elements) also won't work.
So why `registry.byId()` possibly won't work for me? I'm new to AMD-style and the code already worked with the old syntax using `dijit.byId`.

**Edit:**

I figured out that the widget is not registered in the registry-object. What could be the reason for that? If the template could not be found I would get a error 404, so this reason we can exclude.

**Edit2:**

Also `document.getElementById()` will just return `null`. I thought passing the templateString would be enough and dojo does everything else?

Comment: What is responsible for initially creating/placing `startCalculationButton`?

Comment: I forgot to paste one line of Code. Im pulling the template with dojo/text! as mentioned in the [dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html) and passing this string to `templateString`-Member. Do I have more to do for getting this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html#dijit-widgetsintemplatemixin) the widget needs besides `_TemplatedMixin` also `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` and inherit from it:

> But what if we want to have a widget inside of the template, as in:
>
> ```
> <div class="combinedDateTime">
>    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"></div>
>    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox"></div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> When using this template in a directly extended widget class, you will
>   need to mixin dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin in addition to
>   dijit._TemplatedMixin.

Since the dijit-button will be a widget inside my template so adding `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` and inheriting from it solved my problem without the need of other changes. My code looks now something like this (shortened):

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/registry", "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/text!./templates/template.html"],
function(declare, registry, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, templateStringContent) {

return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],
{
    templateString: templateStringContent,

    postCreate() {
       this._setupButton();
    },
    _setupButton: function() {
       buttonWidget = registry.byId("startCalculationButton");
       buttonWidget.set("disabled", true);
    },
});
```

Comment: Great answer, solved my issue, I couldn't retrieve a string id from a widget template and now I can after adding that

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there are something that might be needing specific concern in your code:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/registry"
], function(
    ready,
    dijitRegistry
) {
    ready( function() {
        var grid = dijitRegistry.byId("startCalculationButton");
        console.info(grid)
        grid.set("disbaled", true);
    });
});
```

I think it should be:
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/registry"], function(ready, **registry**) { ... }
and then you may use **registry**.byId("somename")

if you are using dgrid/extensions/**DijitRegistry** on your require syntax, 
then you shall include **DijitRegistry** after your require syntax (kindly remind, it is case-sensitive), but based on my experience, I only used this for dgrid mixin...

Hope this can help...

Comment: mh... now I'm a bit confused. When I posted my Question der JSFiddle worked... now it isn't working and I understand why you posted this hint. But changing the fiddle like you recommend does not help and the JSFIddle still does not work for me... I'm really confused now...

Comment: This is my version after editing: https://jsfiddle.net/1x3dat6e/14/ the button won't be showing up, but at least it can read what grid is (the button)

Comment: Thank you! I updated the original post with the new link. Unfortunately your ideas don't help me with my actual problem. See original post.

Comment: And... how about this, https://jsfiddle.net/1x3dat6e/50/ I noticed that you haven't included the claro css, so the button won't be showing... and then, I have it re-coded, using dom/ready as you written before

Comment: You can see this link too: https://jsfiddle.net/1x3dat6e/52/   My point is, you have to let dojo parser parse your HTML document first, so it can be recognized by the dijit/registry...

Comment: Perhaps, you need to include the dijit/form/Button first. dijit/form/Button cannot be automatically detected if you never include it first... (in require section)

Comment: I included dijit/form/button with no effect. The strange thing ist that even document.getElementById does not work und returns `null`. No matter if I use `parser.parse()` or `ready()`

Comment: Does this really matter? I know it is good practice to keep the require callback arguments self-descripting, but I just renamed a random resource to "foo" in the parameters and it worked (off course I renamed it back just after this) - the order of the arguments is what matters. As an attempt to teach the OP fish in other situation it is not bad, though this won't help in this case.